# why does my pandas dataframe table doesn't render in my tex file?

Tags: tables, pylatex

I'm trying to generate a latex file with a table generated from a Pandas dataframe without success.

I'm using pylatex library to generate the entire file

The example code is as follows:

```
geometry_options = {"tmargin": "1cm", "lmargin": "10cm"}
doc = Document(geometry_options=geometry_options)

with doc.create(Section("Top 10 canales")) as target:
    target.append(df.to_latex())

doc.generate_pdf('full', clean_tex=False)
```

The output of `print(df.to_latex())` is:

```
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
{} &    ATCCO \\
\midrule
All channels        &  16395.0 \\
OLATV\_El Trece      &   4421.0 \\
OLATV\_TN            &   2801.0 \\
OLATV\_Telefe        &   2113.0 \\
OLATV\_ESPN 2        &   1632.0 \\
OLATV\_Atcco Canal 2 &   1361.0 \\
OLATV\_America       &    925.0 \\
TV Publica          &    838.0 \\
OLATV\_Fox Sports 2  &    536.0 \\
OLATV\_ESPN          &    497.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

If i change the `Section()` statement for the `Tabular()` statement it returns an error at the time of compiling into pdf

The final tex file is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage{geometry}%
\geometry{tmargin=1cm,lmargin=10cm}%
%
%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\section{Top 10 canales}%
\label{sec:Top10canales}%
\textbackslash{}begin\{tabular\}\{lr\}\newline%
\textbackslash{}toprule\newline%
\{\} \&    ATCCO \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}\newline%
\textbackslash{}midrule\newline%
All channels        \&  16395.0 \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}\newline%
OLATV\textbackslash{}\_El Trece      \&   4421.0 \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}\newline%
OLATV\textbackslash{}\_TN            \&   2801.0 \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}\newline%
OLATV\textbackslash{}\_Telefe        \&   2113.0 \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}\newline%
OLATV\textbackslash{}\_ESPN 2        \&   1632.0 \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}\newline%
OLATV\textbackslash{}\_Atcco Canal 2 \&   1361.0 \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}\newline%
OLATV\textbackslash{}\_America       \&    925.0 \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}\newline%
TV Publica          \&    838.0 \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}\newline%
OLATV\textbackslash{}\_Fox Sports 2  \&    536.0 \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}\newline%
OLATV\textbackslash{}\_ESPN          \&    497.0 \textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}\newline%
\textbackslash{}bottomrule\newline%
\textbackslash{}end\{tabular\}\newline%

%
\end{document}
```

Without the render:

[image]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The `tabular` output is set *verbatim*-like in the TeX code. You may have to play around with the switch `escape=False` (saw it here: [Python: Pandas to latex - Issues with the backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30499379/914686))

Comment: `\textbackslash{}begin\{tabular\}\{lr\}` makes the text `\begin{tabular}{lr}` in the typeset output,  you want `\begin{tabular}{lr}` in the source.

Comment: @Imran this is the output when using `Tabular()` `! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.14 \begin{tabular}{Top 10 canales}
                                    %

Overfull \hbox (1421.54367pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 14--33
[][]`

Comment: @Werner tried with the parameter `escape = False` and still get the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output from `df.to_latex()` is a string with LaTeX code in it. This does not fit into the normal processing model of PyLaTeX, which is to generate all elements in a document using the relevant Python classes (like `Document()`, `Section()`, `Tabular()` etc). The input for `Section.append()` is expected to be regular text, and if there are any LaTeX symbols in this input they are escaped with `\textbackslash`, `\&` and others.

For this type of situation PyLaTeX has the class `NoEscape()`, which switches off the special character processing. This is explained further on the manual page https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/usage.html#plain-latex-strings. In this case you need `NoEscape(df.to_latex())`.

MWE:

```python
from pylatex import Document, Package, Section, NoEscape
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["All channels", 16395],["OLATV_El Trece",4421.0]],columns=["channel", "ATTCCO"])

geometry_options = {"tmargin": "1cm", "lmargin": "10cm"}
doc = Document(geometry_options=geometry_options)
doc.packages.append(Package('booktabs'))

with doc.create(Section("Top 10 canales")) as target:
    target.append(NoEscape(df.to_latex()))

doc.generate_pdf('full', clean_tex=False)
```

Result:

[image]

Note that I added the `booktabs` package to the document because it is required by `to_latex()` from Pandas. Also there seems to be a bug in `to_latex()` that causes an empty column to be skipped in the output, therefore I provided a column name for the first column as well.

---

For the empty column name a workaround is to use `to_latex(multicolumn=False)`, see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20008. Code:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame([["All channels", 16395],["OLATV_El Trece",4421.0]],columns=["", "ATTCCO"])

with doc.create(Section("Top 10 canales")) as target:
    target.append(NoEscape(df.to_latex(multicolumn=False)))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Marijn !! I was going crazy about this